# Android 8: firebase default notification icon not showing up

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, android-8.0-oreo, android-push-notification

I'm using firebase FCM for my app, and I set up my own notification icon in Manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_custom" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

In every Android before Oreo that I've tested (API 21, API 23) the icon correctly appears in the push notification view, as a big circle with `colorPrimary` background and a white `ic_custom` inside.

In Android 8.0 the icon appears as a small circle filled of `colorPrimary`, whithout any icon inside.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved updating the FCM dependency to `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2`